# Python Selenium visible element not being located

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape [mail.com](https://mail.com) to get the first two emails and everything works well to the point where its finally time to get the mails. Then it gives me an error and crashes the program, saying that the element could not be located while it's clearly visible. Any ideas on how to get around this? I've tried using XPATH and CSS_SELECTOR both and it shows up when searched on inspect.

This is the exception:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#maillist"}
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.110); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF60B2D4A62+57106]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B24CF52]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B11E2CB]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B15786E]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B15795C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B190477]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B1769FF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B18E522]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B176793]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B14CE81]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B14E064]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF60B584222+2873042]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF60B5D6590+3209792]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF60B5CF3AF+3180639]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF60B365F25+652245]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B258618]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B2547C4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B2548BC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF60B244C33]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFAE7C87614+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFAE99A26F1+33]
```

This is the program:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from time import sleep

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Variables
    email = input("Email: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    #Xpaths
    login_form_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/header/div[1]/div[3]/a[2]"
    email_input_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/input"
    password_input_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input"
    login_button_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/button"
    email_screen_xpath = "/html/body/nav/nav-actions-menu/div[1]/div[1]/a[2]"
    inbox_table_div_xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]"

    #Initiate driver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.mail.com/")

    #Go to login
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, login_form_xpath)))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, login_form_xpath).click()

    #Input Email / Password
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, email_input_xpath)))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, email_input_xpath).send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, password_input_xpath).send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, login_button_xpath).click()

    #Go to emails
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, email_screen_xpath)))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, email_screen_xpath).click()

    #Get emails
    sleep(15)
    # table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, inbox_table_div_xpath)
    table = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#maillist")
    with open('abc.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(table.get_attribute("innerHtml"))

    sleep(300)
```

I know that the elements are completely loaded because I am not running headless and by the time the sleep function is over, the elements are clearly visible

Comment: Are you sure the site's completely loaded before you make that request? This happens when that element is not completely in and you try to get it

Comment: Yes I'm sure, as I mentioned the browser has the page completely loaded by the time I try to get the webelement

Comment: Use `WebDriverWait` instead of `sleep`

Comment: Check if there is an `IFRAME` which is wrapping the desired element?

Comment: I was using `WebDriverWait` initially but it would always timeout, practically bringing us to the same issue

Comment: Did you use ChatGPT to write the code above?

Comment: @Shawn There is no `IFRAME` around the desired element, the whole page body is inside one

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Ouch! No I just wrote this myself

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the HTML of this page in the form of text?

Comment: The HTML text to too large. I'm running out of characters

Comment: Ok I cannot log in as I don't have un and pwd to inspect the web elements. Hope someone manages to log in and inspect the elements and find the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

`#maillist` is placed in `iframe`, so to get this element, you need to switch to that frame.

Here is line of code that does that before table init:

```js
#Get emails
// after sleep (I suggest to use WebDriverWait(driver, seconds).until instead to wait for iframe element)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-test=third-party-frame_mail]"))
table = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#maillist")
```